# Lower Bound of the Integral $\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have been trying to find a lower bound of the form $c\frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$ the following integral. Let $x > 1$ and $\Phi(x)$ be the normal distribution CDF.

\begin{align*}
1 - \Phi(x) &= \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}dt \\
            &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y+x)^{2}}{2}}dy \\
            &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2} - xy -\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}dy \\
            &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2
}}e^{-xy}dy \\
&\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2
}}e^{-xy}dy \\
&\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}} \int_{0}^{1}e^{-xy}e^{-xy}dy \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}} \Big(\frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{2x}e^{-2x} \Big)
\end{align*}

I am trying to deal with $\Big(\frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{2x}e^{-2x} \Big)$. If I get just get rid of the extra $\frac{1}{2x}e^{-2x}$ I would get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}} \Big(\frac{1}{2x}\Big) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}$ and be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last step you only need to bound
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}} \Big(\frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{2x}e^{-2x} \Big)\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}} \frac{1-e^{-2}}{2x}.
\end{equation}
Then you have your bound with $c=\frac{1-e^{-2}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

That also is a possible action, since $x> 1$, $1-e^{-2x}$ is a monotonically decreasing function, and $ \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}}{2x}$ is non-negative.